# String getting incorrectly parsed to datetime format in Scala

Tags: scala, datetime

I have a method as follows:

```
def checkDateFormat(dateStr: String): Any = {
val dateFormats = List(
  "yyyy/MM/dd",
  "MM/dd/yyyy",
  "MMM dd, yyyy",
  "dd MMM yyyy",
  "yyyy-MM-dd"
)

dateFormats.foreach(format => {
  try {
      val date = new SimpleDateFormat(format).parse(dateStr)
      return format
  }
  catch {
    case e: Exception => {
      println("Exception")
      /* do nothing */
    }
  }
})
return
}
```

Here, I am trying to identify the  *date format*  of an input string. The way I go about it is to iterate over all `dateFormats` and try to parse the string using `SimpleDateFormat`. If it is correctly parsed, then I return the format, else I let the `catch` block handle it. This method works great for most cases except for if I try to parse:

```
 val inputStr = "02/02/2017"
 val dateFormat = checkDateFormat(inputStr)
```

In this case, for some reason `inputStr` is parsed by `yyyy/MM/dd` instead of getting handled by `catch` (I want it to be parsed by `MM/dd/yyyy` instead). Is there a different way I should be parsing these strings (eg. only through regex pattern matching) or is there another way I can get the example correctly parsed?

Edit: I would prefer not to use `regex` as I would like to add more formats into `dateFormats` and it would be tedious, but if there is no other option, I'm open to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simpler way to write this function:

```
def checkDateFormat(dateStr: String): Option[String] = {
  val dateFormats = List(
    "yyyy/MM/dd",
    "MM/dd/yyyy",
    "MMM dd, yyyy",
    "dd MMM yyyy",
    "yyyy-MM-dd"
  )

  def validFormat(df: String) =
    Try{new SimpleDateFormat(df).parse(dateStr)}.isSuccess

  dateFormats.find(validFormat)
}
```

Using `find` means that this will return as soon as a working format is found.

If you want the actual date, try this:

```
def parseDate(dateStr: String): Option[Date] = {
  dateFormats
    .view
    .map(df => Try{new SimpleDateFormat(df).parse(dateStr)})
    .find(_.isSuccess)
    .flatMap(_.toOption)
}
```

In this case, using `view` ensures that parsing stops as soon as a valid format is found.

Answer (score 0):

From the [java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

> For parsing, if the number of pattern letters is more than 2, the year is interpreted literally, regardless of the number of digits. So using the pattern "MM/dd/yyyy", "01/11/12" parses to Jan 11, 12 A.D.

In this case it's intepreted as year 2AD:

```
@ new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY/MM/dd").parse(inputStr)
res8: java.util.Date = Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 PST 2
```

---

One option is to regex pattern match before doing these tests.

Comment: e.g. `inputStr.matches(raw"\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}")`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the more reliable `java.time` API and replacing `try-catch` with `Try` as follows:

```
def checkDateFormat(dateStr: String): String = {
  import java.time.LocalDate
  import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
  import scala.util.Try

  val dateFormats = List(
    "yyyy/MM/dd",
    "MM/dd/yyyy",
    "MMM dd, yyyy",
    "dd MMM yyyy",
    "yyyy-MM-dd"
  )

  dateFormats.dropWhile( format =>
    Try( LocalDate.parse(dateStr, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format)) ).isFailure
  ).
  headOption match {
    case Some(fmt) => fmt
    case None => "No Match!"
  }
}

checkDateFormat("2018/05/21")
// res1: String = yyyy/MM/dd

checkDateFormat("05/21/2018")
// res2: String = MM/dd/yyyy

checkDateFormat("May 21, 2018")
// res3: String = MMM dd, yyyy

checkDateFormat("2018 05 21")
// res4: String = No Match!
```